# Stop ReSharper formatting C# field attributes

Tags: c#, resharper, code-formatting

In Unity, attributes are often used to format the inspector window for a component. To make things look tidy in the code, I have my code look like this:

```
[Header("Items")]
[SerializeField] private NamedAction[] items;

[Space]

[Header("References")]
[SerializeField] private Button button;
[SerializeField] private RectTransform template;
[SerializeField] private RectTransform templateItem;
```

However, ReSharper wants to format this to look like this:

```
[Header("Items")] [SerializeField] private NamedAction[] items;

[Space] [Header("References")] [SerializeField] private Button button;
[SerializeField] private RectTransform template;
[SerializeField] private RectTransform templateItem;
```

This hurts readability, especially in more complex components. I'm wondering which option can be used to disable this behaviour.

There is an option *"Line Breaks and Wrapping -> Other -> Place field attribute on same line"*, but this will still mess with my attributes formatting. I would like to tell ReSharper to never touch my field attributes.

Comment: Also, I do have "Line Breaks and Wrapping -> Preserve Existing Formatting -> Keep existing line breaks" checked, but it still messes up my attributes formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same issue today, and the only solution I can find is to completely turn off the formatter for those lines.

This can be achieved with

```
// @formatter:off
[Header("Items")]
[SerializeField] private NamedAction[] items;

[Space]

[Header("References")]
[SerializeField] private Button button;
[SerializeField] private RectTransform template;
[SerializeField] private RectTransform templateItem;
// @formatter:on
```

**However** doing this pushes the unformatted fields to the bottom of the file, and I have not yet found a solution for that. I'm actively playing with ReSharper's File Layout. I'll update this answer if I find a solution for that part.